# Core Data NSSortDescriptor with two keys

Tags: swift, sorting, core-data, nssortdescriptor

Is it possible to sort a request by more than one Core Data attribute key?

```
sort1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "list_item", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare))
sort2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "list_item_completed", ascending: true)

request.sortDescriptors = [sort1]
//request.sortDescriptors = [sort1, sort2]
```

I've tried creating an array and adding it to the `sortDescriptor` but it only reflected the first sort.  I have even tried also using the `sortDescriptors` in series with no luck:

```
request.sortDescriptors = [sort1]
request.sortDescriptors = [sort2]
```

Comment: `request.sortDescriptors = [sort1, sort2]` *is* the correct way. If that does not work then you'll have to provide a concrete example of actual and expected result.

Answer (score 2):

The second sort descriptor gets applied only if the first sort descriptor returns equal for the objects that are get compared.

I assume you want to show the list of items completed first in alphabetical order and them un completed again in alphabetical order. In that case,
Jus add sort2 to the array first and then add sort1.